# mobile broadband issue in 12.04

Tags: networking

I installed 12.04 few days back . and mobile broadband ( Reliance netconnect+ ) was working fine .
However since yesterday, it is not working ... mobile braodband option is disabled and not enabling even if I am checking the option. I cant digest this sudden change.

PS. day before yesterday, network bar was not showing while internet was wroking fine .

Answer (score 1):

The default network manager from Ubuntu has no redial option for usb modems which is the cause for all problems

Here's what I did to fix my connection issues with MTS blaze.

Install Gnome-PPP which is a front-end for WvDial

Run the below command in terminal to install.

> sudo apt-get install gnome ppp

And for the disabled network icon here's a [quickfix](http://solancer.blogspot.in/2011/10/network-icon-disappeared-in-ubuntu-1110.html) :